# Forwarding credentials with ASP.net WebClient

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, webclient, credentials

I have a basic asmx page which requests data from a reporting services server.

The User, Web Server running the asmx and the reporting services server are all on the same windows domain.

```
Webclient request = new WebClient();
request.Credentials = ?WhatGoesHere?;
byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData(......)
```

If I set `UseDefaultCredentials = true;` it tries to authenticate using the credentials of the user running IIS.

How do I get the WebClient to authenticate as the user accessing the asmx page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that you have integrated authentication enabled on the web server hosting the aspx page and that the server is IIS.
if the page is not on the reporting server then you may be experiencing the [double hop](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx) issue related to authentication forwarding. the solution requires kerberos authentication and proper configuration of a few items at the domain level.

Comment: Yes, Integrated authentication is enabled on the webserver. And yes, reporting services is on a different server to IIS.

Comment: if you have IIS on the reporting server you can make a try moving the aspx page on that server. if with that layout the aspx page works then it is likely the double hop is the culprit.